# TYPO3 v9.5 does not show template Module on the left side

Tags: php, templates, typo3, typo3-9.x

What happened to the Template Module at the left side from TYPO3? The newest version does not have it. So how do I set up settings for TypoScript, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can still edit templates in list module. To get Template module back you need to load corresponding package into your project: `composer require typo3/cms-tstemplate`.